# What are Shopify public app server specifications

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I had checked the official development documentation site about the best practices and guidelines for creating public apps.

However, I can't find any information about the server requirements for public apps.

I understand that it's impossible to have the best performance from the start but at least I would like to get an idea of the basic requirements.

For example, I plan to host the app on AWS what would be a good instance type?

Comment: server specification base on your **application functionality** and **user traffic**, I mean what kind of functionality you are providing in your application, like Shopify webhooks, Shopify frontend uses, and many more things. it can be work on Basic Droplet of the digital ocean also there is no issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are no server specifications for Shopify.

It's all on you to decide where to host your app, the only thing Shopify cares is for the App to be secure. It can be uploaded on the slowest server and it will still pass.

While the approval process seems a bit overwhelming at first Shopify actually doesn't care about your codebase and does not review it and I can't hold them accountable since you can write Shopify apps on any backend language.

So the answer simply is -> upload it to your favorite hosting provider and don't overthink it.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I see, so it's not part of the approval process.
I will give it a go with the specs we think might go good but still, I would like to have some advice based on the experience of other developers.